# How to get last visible item in QTreeView

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I have a QModelIndex of item in QTreeView.

How to test is this item is last visible item in QTreeView?

Fox example:

```
-item1 // expanded
--sub11
--sub12
-item2 // collapsed
--sub21
```

Function `bool isItemVisible( QModelIndex idx );` should return `true` for item2, and `false` for sub21.

Note that rows may have different height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have made the following sketch for the possible function that will tell you whether your item is the last one in the tree view hierarchy:

The function itself:

```
bool isItemVisible(QTreeView *view, const QModelIndex &testItem,
                   const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QAbstractItemModel *model = view->model();
    int rowCount = model->rowCount(index);
    if (rowCount > 0) {
        // Find the last item in this level of hierarchy.
        QModelIndex lastIndex = model->index(rowCount - 1, 0, index);
        if (model->hasChildren(lastIndex) && view->isExpanded(lastIndex)) {
            // There is even deeper hierarchy. Drill down with recursion.
            return isItemVisible(view, testItem, lastIndex);
        } else  {
            // Test the last item in the tree.
            return (lastIndex == testItem);
        }    
    } else {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

How to use:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTreeView view;
    MyModel model; // The QAbstractItemModel.
    view->setModel(&model);

    QModelIndex indexToTest = model.index(3, 0); // Top level item (4-th row).
    // Start testing from the top level nodes.
    bool result = isItemVisible(&view, indexToTest, QModelIndex());

    return a.exec();
}
```

Please note, that I haven't intensively tested this function, but I think it will work fine. You can, of course, improve it.

**UPDATE:**

After discussing the proposed method, I suggest the following solution that will decrease the number of function calls and improve overall performance.

```
// Returns the last visible item in the tree view or invalid model index if not found any.
QModelIndex lastVisibleItem(QTreeView *view, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex())
{
    QAbstractItemModel *model = view->model();
    int rowCount = model->rowCount(index);
    if (rowCount > 0) {
        // Find the last item in this level of hierarchy.
        QModelIndex lastIndex = model->index(rowCount - 1, 0, index);
        if (model->hasChildren(lastIndex) && view->isExpanded(lastIndex)) {
            // There is even deeper hierarchy. Drill down with recursion.
            return lastVisibleItem(view, lastIndex);
        } else  {
            // Test the last item in the tree.
            return lastIndex;
        }    
    } else {
        return QModelIndex();
    }
}
```

Define a variable that will keep track of the last visible item in the tree. For example:

```
static QModelIndex LastItem;
```

Update the cached item each time the tree view items expanded or added/removed. This can be achieved in the slot that connected to QTreeView's `expanded()`, `collapsed()`, `:rowsAboutToBeInserted`, `rowsAboutToBeRemoved()` signals, i.e

```
..
{
    LastItem = lastVisibleItem(tree);
}
```

Finally, to test a tree view item, just compare its model index with this `LastItem` without calling search function again.

Comment: Idea is good, thanks. But I got performance issues, because I need to call this function for each item on each paint event. I think that I should go somehow throught `indexAt` method. I'll accept this answer later, if no more solutions will be found.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, if you are going to call it too intensively, maybe it makes sense to cache the result and use it if nothing has changed (for example if no node was expanded or added)?

Comment: It will be hard to track expanded/collapsed state for items, and to track new items. Currently it is minor bug, related to drawing last row bottom border.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, I have updated the answer with extended information.

Comment: Thanks, that good. Also I'll track model reset events and all should be fine.